# How to Install SDL web 8.5 in Microsoft Azure

Tags: web8.5, sdl-tridion, installation, azure

I have SDL Web 8.5 installation media for trial purpose. I want to install SDL Web  8.5 in Azure, is there any installation guide/steps available? I have done on-premise installation a few years back,  but this time i want to host it on Azure for learning purposes. I am thinking of creating a Single machine Application, like Windows Server as a virtual machine, will install SQL in the same machine, and will run the database script to make Tridion DB's available in my Virtual Machine/Server. Will Host Tridion on the same machine.

Before anything to start is there anything specific which i need to take care? or any installation guide/help to host it in azure is available ?

Answer (score 1):

We use Azure hosted servers all the time, including installing, and there aren't any main differences compared to "regular" installations, especially if you're doing a one-box setup. The prerequisites are the same. But as Jonathan has already mentioned, just be sure to open all the necessary ports in Azure's Network Security Group settings if you wish to access the system from outside.

Answer (score 0):

I've worked with Azure hosted Tridion implementations in the past, so it's definitely possible.

My main advise would be for you to check [the pre-requisites in the Tridion 8.5 online documentation](https://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Web-v5/GUID-B9941B8E-82DD-4551-92BB-F883DEC54EB2) before you begin. Make sure that the version of Window Server, SQL Server and Java installed on your server(s) are all supported.

Also, if you're hosting across multiple servers (e.g. if the database is on a separate server), then make sure all of the necessary ports are open between these. I've lost too many hours to that one! :)